# What does @babel/plugin-transform-block-scoping do that isn't part of babel's core behavior?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, transpiler

[The docs](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-block-scoping) leave a lot to be desired, as is sometimes the case with Babel plugins.

> This plugin also validates all `const` variables. Reassignment of constants is a runtime error and it will insert the necessary error code for those.

I don't know what this means? Isn't that *always* going to cause a runtime error?

And the example it provides only uses `let` and `var` which furthers my confusion.

Comment: What "core behavior" are you referring to in this case? Babel's core doesn't do anything unless you enable plugins.

Comment: Derp, I forgot transpilation to ES5 which doesn't have `const`, but man that doc's language is still confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In es5, `const` does not exist. If you are compiling your code down to es5, all your `const` declarations will become `var` declarations. The plugin will insert runtime code for the `const` values to throw an error if they are assigned a new value, likely by converting references to accessor function calls.